# jQuery Insert set of attributes as string to tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have variable x that contains set of attributes.

`var x = 'class="test test1 test2" id="xyz" style="color:red"';`

How can i insert x to the `<body>` tag. so body looks like

`<body class="test test1 test2" id="xyz" style="color:red">`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're storing it like that? Why not `x = {'class': 'test test1 test2', 'id': 'xyz', 'style': 'color:red'}`? Then you can just do `$('body').attr(x)`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could create a temp element and att attributes to it and then append all of its attributes to the body:

```
var x = 'class="test test1 test2" id="xyz" style="color:red"',
    temp = $("<b "+x+">")[0],
    attr = {};
for (var i=0, attrs=temp.attributes, l=attrs.length; i<l; i++){
    attr[attrs.item(i).nodeName] = attrs.item(i).value;
}

$("body").attr(attr);
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/udilib/edit#javascript,html,live

but if you can then make the class, id and style as an object instead of a string, will save some code for you.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I thought the solution would be allot simpler, but this will do for now.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't bullet-proof, but it seems to handle your example input fine:

```
var x = 'class="test test1 test2" id="xyz" style="color:red"',
    pairs = x.match(/\w+\=\"[^\"]+\"/g),
    $body = $('body');
for (var i = 0, len = pairs.length; i < len; i++) {
    var parts = pairs[i].split('='),
        attrName = parts[0],
        attrValue = parts[1].replace(/\"/g, '');
    $body.attr(attrName, attrValue);
}
```